# Problem with CSS on highlighted code with Highlight.js

Tags: html, css, sass, highlightjs

[My personal site](https://matthewdaly.co.uk/) has a weird CSS issue that only seems to occur on Android devices (it may occur on other mobile devices, but I haven't been able to reproduce it in any non-mobile browsers).

It uses Highlight.js for syntax highlighting, but I've implemented support for line numbers myself. On Android browsers, any lines of code after number 62 are not highlighted correctly, and instead that section appears blank.

The source code is at https://github.com/matthewbdaly/matthewbdaly.github.io, in the `source` branch. The problem appears to be in the file `app/sass/_code.scss`, and a while back I applied [this commit](https://github.com/matthewbdaly/matthewbdaly.github.io/commit/4aca94275a21b7fea8f538665b853764742bdadb#diff-8380061d9f80b7e05134e96f369840a4) to that file to amend the overflow by adding `overflow-x: initial` to the `hljs` class applied to the code by Highlight.js, which solved that issue, but meant that the background colour only ran the width of the visible section of the syntax highlighting, and if you scrolled it horizontally it visibly had a different background colour, so I wound up reverting it.

My CSS skills are somewhat pedestrian, and I haven't been able to come up with a solution for this. Any idea how I might resolve this?